# PowerBi: I would like to know how many locations have a collection vs. the count of all items within a collection in a location...how do I do that?

Tags: powerbi, iteration, countif

Super new so please forgive me :-)

In Excel, I would have done an iterative sumif($a$1:a1) and then countifs( all the ones that say "1" vs. higher numbers:
example  iterative
Blue     1
blue     2
green    1
red      1
purple   1
green    2

I have 2 tables(fields): FloorSamples(location,sku) and ItemData(sku, collection)

Here is the output I am looking for:
Collection     #stores that have that collection

Since collections have multiple items to complete a group I receive this output instead:
Collection     #items that have that collection label

If 12 locations have a collection, and there are 5 items per store that have that collection name, I would like it to return 12, not 60.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a many-to-one relationship between FloorSamples.sku and ItemData.sku, use this measure in a visual with Collections as a dimension (rows or axis), you will get what you're looking for.

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(FloorSamples[location])
```